# Can't import RealityKit on Xcode 13 Beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, realitykit

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Error

> ❌ Failed to build module 'RealityKit' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug

> ❌ Swift Compiler Error
> ❌
> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/RealityKit.framework/Modules/RealityKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:239:44: Version for 'macCatalyst' already specified

#### What's happen

I try to import the RealityKit on Xcode 13 beta 4, with the simple steps

1. Create a new project
2. at ContentView.swift, add import RealityKit

then, Xcode presents an error

#### What've done

This version of Xcode can't import RealityKit

1. clear build
2. remove a derived folder

By the way, if there is no way to solve this problem yet by ourself (only Apple can solve this problem), so the good news is Xcode 13 Beta 3 still recognizes the iPadOS 15 beta 4 without the need to downgrade.